# (Kali & Ettercap) Plugin compilation error

Tags: c, ettercap

Okay I'm having a particular issue during compilation using the command `gcc -shared -o attack_test.so -fPIC attack_test.c`. Specifically, when I run the command, I get the error `fatal error: ec.h: No such file or directory`. Any idea how to fix this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT:** To give a little more issue background, I'm running this command from the desktop, where my C source code is located. Perhaps there's a specific place I need to put the source and run the command?

**EDIT 2:** So I was able to get past the above error by running the command `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`, and then changing the line `#include <ec.h>` to `#include <openssl/ec.h>`, which seemed to negate the issue. Adding the `<openssl/...>` to the other includes did not work the same way. So now, instead of `fatal error: ec.h: No such file or directory`, it's `fatal error: ec_plugins.h: No such file or directory`. Any ideas for possible fixes? Thanks so much!

For reference, I'm building upon the the dos_attack.c source code from [this link](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/blob/master/plug-ins/dos_attack/dos_attack.c).

**TO BE CLEAR:** This is for a project and tested upon in a *CLOSED ENVIRONMENT*. This is COMPLETELY* for EDUCATIONAL use and for the study of Denial-of-Service and Man-In-the-Middle mitigation techniques.

Answer (score 1):

`<ec.h>` is intended to refer to [a file in the Ettercap `include` directory](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap/blob/master/include/ec.h), not an OpenSSL header. The same goes for the other `ec_*.h` headers.

Adding `-I/path/to/ettercap/include` to your compiler flags should fix this.

Comment: I've seen this solution while doing my research on this error, but I'm not really sure how to add it to the `gcc -shared -o attack_test.so -fPIC attack_test.c` command. Can you please give an example so I know how to correctly do it? Thank you so much!

Comment: And check whether there's a `pkg-config` to make it easier.

Comment: @Aidan Use the Ettercap build scripts. They should take care of this for you.

Comment: @duskwuff could you please be more specific? I'm very new to Ettercap and am not sure where these scripts would be or how to use them! Thank you for helping a newbie out!